# Filter many2one in one2many based on another many2one in odoo 8

Tags: python-2.7, one-to-many, odoo-8, many-to-one

my problem is following:

I have two one2many fields in my `class Agreement` which each contains a many2one field referring to the `class Unit`.

I want to be able to select some Units in `agreement_invoice_ids` and the Units in `agreement_info_ids` should automatically be filtered based one this selection.

I tried using a domain in the xml, setting up the domain in python, different functions using api.onchange and api.depends. I hope that it is actually possible and I just missed the correct thing to do.

I greatly take any piece of advise.

Below a simplified version of my code:

**agreement.py**

```
class Agreement(models.Model):
    _name = 'model.agreement'

    agreement_invoice_ids = fields.One2many('model.invoice', 'agreement_id')
    agreement_info_ids = fields.One2many('model.info', 'agreement_id')


class Invoice(models.Model):
    _name = 'model.invoice'

    agreement_id = fields.Many2one('model.agreement')
    unit_id = fields.Many2one('model.unit')


class Info(models.Model):
    _name = 'model.info'

    agreement_id = fields.Many2one('model.agreement')
    unit_id = fields.Many2one('model.unit')
```

**agreement.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="agreement_form_view">
            <field name="name">agreement.form</field>
            <field name="model">model.agreement</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Agreement Form">

                    <field name="agreement_invoice_ids">
                        <tree editable="bottom">
                            <field name="unit_id"/>
                        </tree>
                    </field>

                    <field name="agreement_info_ids">
                        <tree editable="bottom">
                            <field name="unit_id"/> <!-- should be filtered based on selection made for unit_id in agreement_invoice_ids -->
                        </tree>
                    </field>

                </form>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out.

Just do the following and you're golden.

```
class Info(models.Model):
    _name = 'model.info'

    agreement_id = fields.Many2one('model.agreement')
    unit_id = fields.Many2one('model.unit')

    @api.multi
    @api.onchange('unit_id')
    def filter_unit_id(self):
        res = dict()
        unit_ids = self.agreement_id.agreement_invoice_ids.mapped('unit_id.id')
        res['domain'] = {'unit_id': [('id', 'in', unit_ids)]}
        return res
```

Comment: @gve Perfect answer, Thank You :)